# Не воспроизводится звук при движении объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

При движении по горизонтали или вертикали `m_Clip` должна воспроизводить звук, но звук не работает. Пробывал делать проверку на воспроизведение звука, но тоже не помогло. Почему такое может быть? Возможна ли проблема в том что я использую джойстик? Но я поставил настройках Input manager тип джойстик. Cнизу прилагаю код.

```
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource m_Clip;
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(sound());
    }
    private IEnumerator sound()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0)
        {
            m_Clip.Play();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Да просто он может банально не успевать воспроизводится.... в update его вызывать.....

Comment: В корутине с задержкой он тоже не воспроизводится.

Comment: Напишите в корутине Debug.Log что-нибудь, вывод в консоль редактора есть? Отлаживали вообще код? Точку останова ставили? Или сразу вопрос писать? Скрипт то выполняется вообще?

Comment: Вот именно то, что он не работает и DebugLog не выводится в консоль. Это вообще 3 версия кода

Comment: Запихни весь существующий код корутины в бесконечный цикл

Comment: 1) нужно видеть весь код скрипта, а не обрывок 2) убедитесь, что скрипт висит на действующем объекте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допишите:

```
... else yield return null;
```

и оберните содержимое метода `sound` в бесконечный цикл. Реализация не очень, но работать будет.